# Android: location of my database file

Tags: android, database, file, path, backup

With

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String path = db.getPath();
```

I know that my database file is at the path `/data/data/com.packagename/databases/app.db`.

The user of my should have access to this file to backup the data for example that he changes the mobile phone. I tried to find it via Windows Explorer but there is no folder in `/data` that is called like this.

I also searched the database file via the search but no sucess. Isn´t it possible to get it in this way?

Comment: If you want it to be accessible to the user you will need to provide some kind of "export" that will dump the db file, or all of its data onto the external storage. `data/` is not accessible for reading unless the device has root

Answer (score 1):

Files under the application's private internal storage are not accessible by the end-user USB Mass Storage or MTP file access mechanisms.

Unless you explicitly set the permissions for general access or are testing a debug APK or on a debug device, they are not accessible with the adb & ddms developer tools either.

Your options would include storing the database on the External Storage instead, or having a menu in your app which would give the user the option of making a *copy* of it there, while the original remains in your app's private folder comparatively immune from meddling by other apps as could happen if it were on the ownerless External Storage.

Comment: You should not be storing sqlite databases on external storage. This is for technical reasons, see: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64345

Comment: What is discussed here is primarily *copying* the db to external storage to share it with analysis tools.  Further, you are pointing to one person's rather debateable *opinion*.

Comment: The user should have access to the file, not a copy of the file. Isn't this what you are saying by "storing the database on the External Storage instead"? The "opinion" is not from an individual, but rather "Typically we advise against it" and "we" are Google's Android Engineers.

Comment: It is advice from an individual reflecting biases common on the android team, and not necessarily shared by those who view the phone as a compact unix workstation and desire to preserve the capability naturally implied by that. Its technical basis also seems questionable, as on current devices the external storage is implemented as an emulation layer on top of the internal storage

Comment: The technical basis is valid because it is at least true for some devices (Nexus One, for example) and may be true for future devices. Therefore the technical issue must be considered. Privacy and security must also be considered. What does the CTS say regarding external storage? Advice from the Android team should at least be listened to. They might know something about future development that is influencing this advice. Anyway, it's certainly worthy of a comment in an SO answer ;) I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Basically that comment is an android version of the infamous "Your're holding it wrong" - ie, someone making excuses for the fact that there's a bug in the platform, by giving hand-waving reasons why they believe you shouldn't try to use that capability anyway.  Developers and device owners are free to evaluate the *actual* risks for a *specific* use themselves.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible if you don't have a rooted phone. If you have a rooted phone you can get it with ADB by executing

```
adb pull /data/data/com.packagename/databases/app.db
```